# PHP session_unset doesn't clear the $_SESSION variable

Tags: php, session

Having simple PHP session example code as follow:

session_set.php:

```
...
// Start the session
session_set_cookie_params(0, "/", ".local.loc");
session_start();

// Set session variables
$_SESSION["favcolor"] = "green";
$_SESSION["favanimal"] = "cat";
```

session_get.php:

```
session_start();
session_unset();
//$_SESSION = array();

echo "Favorite color is " . $_SESSION["favcolor"] . ".<br>";
echo "Favorite animal is " . $_SESSION["favanimal"] . ".";
```

the *session_unset* funtion doesn't work - i can still get *favcolor* and *favanimal* values when requesting *session_get.php*...

Comment: You need to call session_start(), then run session_unset(), as you need to start the session in question before you can unset anything from it

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. There is of course _session_start_ call in the _session_get.php_ but the _session_unset_ still doesn't work!

Comment: You could possibly try ob_start(), and although from your example this is true, just make sure session_start is the very first function being called.

Comment: Yes, _session_start_ is the first one operation. Can You test the case on Yours environment and report the results for me?

Comment: Your code as you put it here works fine for me, im not too sure why yours isn't working. I'd also like to mention if you are working on localhost, Chrome does not allow cookies to be set or removed on localhost, so that could be part of the issue? If you have a test domain in your hosts file that might be another test you can try, as chrome will allow test domains to have cookies.

Comment: @dune184 "works fine for me" - does it mean that _session_unset_ works for You - after calling it _$_SESSION["favcolor"]_ and _$_SESSION["favanimal"]_ are undefined?

Comment: Yes the session variables where unset and no longer defined